# Add New Row to a DataGrid in Silverlight WCF RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, service, ria

Some guidance with Silverlight WCF RIA Services... DataGrid and detail view on the same page

```
Control layout
DataGrid
Detail View [Add New Row (button)]
```

If I wanted to add a new row from a button then pick that new row in the datagrid how would I do that?

I have tried:

```
DetailViewTest.Web.Services.Mode1DomainContext ctx = 
       (Mode1DomainContext)wordDomainDataSource.DomainContext;

Word word = new Word()
{
    Word1 = this.word1TextBox.Text,
    DateAdded = DateTime.Now
};
ctx.Words.Add(word);
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

This adds the word to that database but not the datagrid even though the datasource for the data is the wordDomainDataSource. If I restart the application it then shows up in the datagrid. Some help with this would be great!

(Using the Silverlight 4 business Application as a starting project )

Comment: The secret is 
Word word = new Word()
            {
                Word1 = this.word1TextBox.Text,
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now

            };
 wordDomainDataSource.DataView.Add(word);

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MVVM / INotifyPropertyChanged pattern you probably need to fire the OnPropertyChanged event on the ItemSource.